# Why does the `insecure` option not work in maven?

Tags: java, maven, ssl, maven-3

I am running a maven build behind a proxy and I get this error:

> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path

I started simply using the `insecure` option:

```
mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true clean install
```

Nevertheless I get still the same error.

**Why does the `insecure` option not work?**

Comment: `insecure` only relaxes *some* of the checks. You might also need `maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall` and/or `maven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates` depending on what parts of the certs are not okay. See [this page](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/).

Comment: Why do you use that?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Enableing these options did not change the error. I found out that the  [insecure options](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/) enable these options, too.

Comment: As of today, any ot the 3 system properties mentioned before cause no effect. I receive same exception when trying to download something